# How to use Putty in Japanese?

Tags: windows, putty, utf-8

I am trying to use Putty to connect to a Linux server that has a file system that contains unicode characters (specifically Japanese)

My goal is to make it work the way it worked on Mac OS X Terminal app or the standard Gnome Terminal on Linux Mint.

So what I have done successfully so far was connect to the server and get it to display properly when I use "MS Gothic".

However, I "lose" my backslash character as MS Gothic maps it as a yen character.  So using the MS Gothic approach isn't good enough.

I tried to Google some fonts that would have Japanese characters, but none of them appear in Putty's drop down list as they are not monospaced fonts.

So looking for someone to suggest another alternative approach that would work with Putty (i.e. not switching to a different SSH client)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Japanese version of Putty at http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA024651/PuTTYkj.html ( The direct link to the zip file: http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA024651/download/file/putty-0.62-jp20111214.zip )

The menu is all in Japanese by default so in order to display the menu in English, you may rename `puttyjp.lng` to something else like `puttyjp.lng.bak` or simply delete it. Then in the Configuration window, go to Category -> Window -> Translation and you'll find several Japanese encoding in the pull down list including EUC-JP, ISO-2022_jp, and Shift_JIS etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to translate as well as use a good font.  From the [Putty manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/puttydoc.txt):

> 3.3 Altering your character set configuration
>
> ```
>    If you find that special characters (accented characters, for
>    example, or line-drawing characters) are not being displayed
>    correctly in your PuTTY session, it may be that PuTTY is
>    interpreting the characters sent by the server according to the
>    wrong _character set_. There are a lot of different character sets
>    available, so it's entirely possible for this to happen.
>
>    If you click `Change Settings' and look at the `Translation' panel,
>    you should see a large number of character sets which you can
>    select, and other related options. Now all you need is to find out
>    which of them you want! (See section 4.10 for more information.)
> ```

In my version, it's actually under Window->Translation and it's set to `Use font encoding` But there's a lot of options in the drop down that will help.